# SendGrid Message ID not Found in GET /messages/{msg_id}

Tags: javascript, email, sendgrid

I am currently trying to implement SendGrid Email Activity into my application. Whenever an event fires I am able to access the info I need. When trying to look at the message corresponding to the message_id I receive the error: NOT FOUND.

I am wondering if there is a solution for this or has it not yet been created on SendGrid and how would I go about accessing the message information based on an engagement or delivery event?

Thanks

---

```
const env = require('dotenv').config();
const client = require('@sendgrid/client');
client.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
const eventStatus = info.event;
const customerAccountNumber = info.customerAccountNumber;
const recipient = info.email;
const messageId = info.sg_message_id;

console.log("message ID:", messageId);
try {
  const request = {};
  request.method = 'GET';
  request.url = '/v3/messages/' + messageId;
  client.request(request)
  .then(([response, body]) => {
    console.log(response.statusCode);
    if(response.statusCode == 200) {
      const messageInfo = response.body;
      const sender = messageInfo.from_email;
      const subject = messageInfo.subject;
      
    console.log(eventStatus, customerAccountNumber, sender, recipient, messageId, subject);
    }
    else {
      console.dir("Here");
    }
  });
}
catch(e){
  console.log(e);
}

  return("Test");
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're getting a HTTP 404 because the URL you're putting together is wrong. Given `messageId = 'foobar123'`, the following code

```
  request.url = '/v3/messages/' + messageId;
```

will produce the request URL `"/v3/messages/foobar123"`.

Taking a quick peek at the [docs](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/getting-started-email-activity-api#queries-for-common-use-cases), the URL should be something more like `"/v3/messages?limit=10&query={your_query}"`, with options for `{your_query}` described [here](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/getting-started-email-activity-api#query-reference).

I'm assuming you're trying to make a query such as `msg_id="filter0307p1las1-16816-5A023E36-1.0"`. You need to pass this as URL parameter `query`. You'll also need to URL encode it, since it contains `=` and `"` characters. Putting all of this together, I'd try something like:

```
const query = `msg_id="${messageId}"`;
const request = {};
  request.method = 'GET';
  request.url = `/v3/messages?query=${encodeURIComponent(query)}`;
  client.request(request).then(...)
```